# Default antivirus for mac

Tags: mac

Windows Defender is default antivirus for windows.

I used mac for very brief time, I failed to search for does mac contains default antivirus.

Does mac have default antivirus?

Comment: This is the second question i have seen from Program Idea in a short period.  What have you researched and found out?  Have you looked into it at all your self?  I honestly want to flag the question because of a lack of research on your part.

Comment: I only found free antivirus recommendation stuff. Does mac actually have its native antivirus?

Answer (score 3):

XProtect.

> "The built-in anti-malware protection on Mac OS X is known as “XProtect,” which is technically a feature built into “File Quarantine.” This feature was added  back in 2009 with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard."

[Taken from here](http://www.howtogeek.com/217043/xprotect-explained-how-your-macs-built-in-anti-malware-works/)